# How to get CSS class name value part within the property

Tags: css, sass

Is there any option to get the class name value within property. 
Here, I need 12.

```css
.grid-12{
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use a css preprocessor to do this like sass, less,...

Comment: No there is no option, just use the way @HuyTran said.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like that

`document.querySelector('div').style['grid-template-columns']` you can obviously get the value and then parse it but in my eyes that looks kinda ugly.

The best you can to do is to use a css parser to transform the css into a AST tree and iterate over it. That of course has its own trade-offs and usually doesn't worth to do it in the frontend, its not even 100% sure that the parser will give you that value. e.g. I see that your snippet in a parser is transform to the following AST tree

```
{
  "parentStyleSheet": null,
  "cssRules": [
    {
      "parentRule": null,
      "parentStyleSheet": "[Circular ~]",
      "selectorText": ".grid-12",
      "style": {
        "0": "grid-template-columns",
        "length": 1,
        "parentRule": "[Circular ~.cssRules.0]",
        "_importants": {
          "grid-template-columns": ""
        },
        "__starts": 8,
        "grid-template-columns": "repeat(12, 1fr)"
      },
      "__starts": 0,
      "__ends": 55
    }
  ]
}
```

So again, you have to manually extract the `12`

Comment: Amazing solution but it doesn't worth to do :D

Comment: @HuyTran exactly. :)